# Delete the string starting from any month in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, substring

I have below Oracle sql query which i need to modify:

```
    Select (SUBSTR(long_comp_name, 1, 23)) 
    Kontrakt_Bezeichnung, long_comp_name
    FROM TRT_AGG 
    where ROOT = 'SP';
```

The result of the query is like below:

```
Kontrakt_Bezeichnung                   long_comp_name
    SP Plus Corp                       SP Plus Corp
    SP Plus Corp                       SP Plus Corp 
    SP Plus Corp                       SP Plus Corp
    SP Plus Corp                       SP Plus Corp
    S&P 500 FUTR OPTN Jun20            S&P 500 FUTR OPTN Jun20P 4275
    S&P 500 FUTR OPTN Jun20            S&P 500 FUTR OPTN Jun20P 4275
    S&P 500 FUTR OPTN Jun20            S&P 500 FUTR OPTN Jun20P 4275
    S&P 500 FUTR OPTN Jun20            S&P 500 FUTR OPTN Jun20C 4275
```

Now i want to modify my query such that it will cut the further part of the values from string which is starting from any month. For example in the above example it will cut this complete part from 'Jun20'. For other value it should remain same.

I want to have result like below:

```
Kontrakt_Bezeichnung
        SP Plus Corp 
        SP Plus Corp 
        SP Plus Corp 
        SP Plus Corp 
        S&P 500 FUTR OPTN 
        S&P 500 FUTR OPTN 
        S&P 500 FUTR OPTN 
        S&P 500 FUTR OPTN
```

I am using this query field in Oracle View so for this reason cant use With Clause in select query

Comment: Just a suggestion: Have you considered [regexp_replace](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/regexp_replace.php)?

Comment: sorry no i found substr simple as i have not used regexp before

Comment: You can not get the first result from the query you have provided to us. Add, in your question, one example of the ORIGINAL value from the column long_comp_name when it is simmilar to this: "SP Plus Corp" and one example when it is simmilar to this: "S&P 500 FUTR OPTN Jun20".

Comment: added the result for long_comp_name...i think we can use case condition here right ?

Comment: i have edited my query and question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think you are searching for something like:

```
    with d as (
    select     'SP Plus Corp OPTION' n1 from dual
    union all select 'S+P 500 FUTR OPTN Jun20 OPTION' from dual)
select n1, regexp_replace(n1,'(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun)[0-9]{2}.*','') from d
```

Comment: i have edited my query and question...i am using the field in oracle view so cant use With clause

Comment: you only need the part `regexp_replace(n1,'(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun)[0-9]{2}.*','')` the rest was to make a reproducable example ...

Comment: yes i got the result now but i was checking for Dec month and it was again showing complete value with month...i think i need to add for all months in this regexp

Comment: sure you have to add the remaining 6 months ... thought this wouldn't be a big issue

Comment: i have checked today the complete data again but getting values like below with month name in between. :   FTSE KLCI Options Jun20 OPTION,
SX5E DIVIDEND OPT Dec20 OPTION,
VSTOXX Opt        May20 OPTION,
VSTOXX Opt        Aug20 OPTION,
VSTOXX Opt        Aug20 OPTION,
VSTOXX Opt        Jun20 OPTION,

Comment: If you use | as separator this shouldn't happen `select n1, regexp_replace(n1,'(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Aug|Dec)[0-9]{2}.*','') from d`

Comment: i am using the condition like this is it not correct ? regexp_replace(long_comp_name,'(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[0-21]{2}.*','')

Comment: `[0-21]{2}` is incorrect .. probably you mean `([0-1][0-9]|20|21)`

Comment: sorry yes it was (Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[0-9]{2}.*','') but still its not working for some values..for example one of the value its still showing as FTSE KLCI Options Jun20 OPTION where it should be FTSE KLCI Options

Comment: Jun20 should work when there are no hidden characters